# Neo4j APOC clear manual index

Tags: indexing, neo4j, cypher, neo4j-apoc

I use Neo4j 3.4.0 Community Edition with APOC apoc-3.4.0.1-all.jar

I'm looking for the way how to properly via Cypher/APOC clear manual index.

Right now I'm trying something like that:

```
CALL apoc.index.relationships('HAS_VALUE_ON', '*:*') 
YIELD rel 
WITH rel 
CALL apoc.index.removeRelationshipByName('HAS_VALUE_ON', rel) 
RETURN true
```

but I don't know how to properly provide the `*:*` predicate in order to retrieve all of the relationships from the index.

The current query fails with the following error:

> Neo.ClientError.Security.Forbidden: Write operations are not allowed
>   for user 'neo4j' with FULL restricted to READ.

How to properly clear manual index with Cypher/APOC?

Comment: What edition of neo4j do you use - community or enterprise?

Comment: @stdob--  I use Neo4j 3.4.0 Community Edition

Comment: Your query is absolutely correct - problem with write permission. P.S. You can use the function `apoc.index.remove`.

Comment: @stdob-- thanks, `apoc.index.remove` is what exactly I was looking for